# How to merge a template with a site?

Tags: hugo

[Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) works with themes one can [download](http://themes.gohugo.io/) (or [create from scratch](https://gohugo.io/themes/creation/)). They live in their subfolder of the site root (namely `themes`).

When reading about [customizing themes](https://gohugo.io/themes/customizing/) and playing along, I realized that a theme reproduces the structure of the root site (it has `layout`, `static` and similar folders, same as the root site).

**Is it possible (and not discouraged) to copy a theme over the root of the site, and customize it from there?**

I realize that I will lose the ability to update a theme, but it should not matter that much as i will heavily update it anyway. For completeness, I actually did the copy and my site did not change (it now now built without `--theme=`) but it may just be luck (or discouraged practices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, yes. The main folders from the theme (`layouts`, `static`, `archetypes`, `data`, and `i18n`) can be copied over to the root site folder without any change in functionality. Other folders that you copy over will be ignored (e.g. `exampleSite`). Most files in the root directory (e.g. `theme.toml`) are also ignored. So you should be able to copy everything over and have it just work, unless the theme author decided to put a `config.toml` or a `content` directory in their repo.

However, probably the easiest way to modify a theme is to clone the git repository into the themes directory, create a new branch in git, and make your modifications there. That way you can use git to merge any changes from the main repository into your version. Without git, this takes a lot more work. It also makes it a lot easier to swap your custom theme for a different one - just add the new one to the themes directory and change your `config.toml`.